# Is "we saw in the hall a boy" correct? I think the position of "in the hall" is weird

Tags: sentence-construction

> We saw **in the hall** a boy.

I think the position of "in the hall" is weird. Shouldn't it be "I saw a boy in the hall"?

Comment: I agree. That's a weird phrasing. The other is more common. The first still makes sense though.

Comment: Your example sounds marked due to the postposed object which also happens to be lighter than what it has moved over. That is, "a boy" is lighter than "in the hall" (2 words vs 3 words). The unmarked version is *"We saw [a boy] [in the hall]"*. Usually, the default order would have the direct object pretty much right after the verb. But, also consider some cases when postposing might be preferable by the speaker, such as: *"We saw [in the hall] [an enormous purple-skinned Martian with twelve tentacles wearing yellow-spotted high-ankle sneakers]"*, which has a very heavy direct object.

Comment: How about "We saw, in the hall, a boy."?

Comment: @user3169 Who are you asking your question to? Why add two commas where they are unnecessary? This slows things way down and to me it represents overuse of the comma. Especially in a sentence containing seven words.

Comment: When sentences are not written in the standard order, it doesn't mean they are written incorrectly. Often it means the author wants to stress something.

Comment: But, if you add only one comma, it's classic literature: "We saw in the hall, a boy."

Comment: @pazzo I'll rephrase. Maybe what was meant was "We saw, in the hall, a boy." I am just adding a possible interpretation with minimal changes, since the source (or intent if written by the OP) are not mentioned.

Comment: She, for no reason, condemned it! -even a word lesser but sounds fine! @pazzo It's just a style! :)

Comment: @pazzo But if the sentence was longer, it would just be an appositive... "We saw, in the hall, a boy who looked to be around eight, with slender legs and wide, expressive eyes.

Comment: Yes to both questions: Yes, it's correct, and yes, it's weird.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer, from consensus:**

Yes, that sentence is correct grammatically. Yes, it sounds weird.

**Longer answer, paraphrased from [F.E.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58403/is-we-saw-in-the-hall-a-boy-correct-i-think-the-position-of-in-the-hall-is#comment111406_58403):**

Your example sounds strange due to the [postposed object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition) which also happens to be lighter than what it has moved over.

That is, "a boy" is lighter than "in the hall" (2 words vs 3 words). As you pointed out, the expected version is "We saw [a boy] [in the hall]".

Usually, the default order would have the direct object (a boy) pretty much right after the verb. But, also consider some cases when postposing might be preferable by the speaker, such as

> We saw [in the hall] [an enormous purple-skinned Martian with twelve tentacles wearing yellow-spotted high-ankle sneakers].

which has a very heavy direct object.